# How can I rescale axis without scaling the image in an image plot with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scale

I have a simple image plot like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.arange(25)
data.shape = (5,5)

plt.imshow(data, interpolation='none')
plt.show()
```

In this case the input data a 5x5 matrix. The ticks on the axis go from 0 to 4. How would I go about changing this range to say 10 to 50 without changing the displayed image? I want to rescale the axis without scaling the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the `extent` property of `imshow` you can put any possible range on the axis, without changing the plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.arange(25)
data.shape = (5,5)

plt.imshow(data, interpolation='none', extent=(-3, 27, 5, 31))
plt.show()
```

This gives:

[image]

Comment: Okay, thanks. I was stupid. I tried `extent=[...]` before, but got weird results. You made me realize, that I had a contour-plot overlayed with the actual image. Of cause the countour plot needs an `extent=[...]`, too for a proper display.

Comment: The big difference with a contour plot, is that in the `contour` function you can pass arrays that represent the axes, while `imshow` is just a plain pixel printer.

Answer (score 5):

Generally for any plot you can use `xticks` and `yticks`, e.g.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.arange(25)
data.shape = (5,5)

plt.imshow(data, interpolation='none')
plt.xticks([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [10,20,30,40,50])
plt.yticks([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [10,20,30,40,50])
plt.show()
```

[image]